# lambda expression with *args

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, tuples, args

I know that when we use `*args`, it means we are not sure how many arguments the function is going to receive. However, Python finally binds them together in a single tuple:

```
>>> def f(*args):
    return type(args)

>>> f(3,4,4,5)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Suppose I have a simple function that returns the input unchanged. I can use it with a nested lambda like this:

```
>>> def f (x):
    return x

>>> l = f(lambda x: len(x))
>>> 
>>> l((1,2,3))
3
```

Note that the input is a tuple. However, this is what happens when I try to write the same function with `args`:

```
>>> def f (*args):
    return args

>>> l = f(lambda x: len(x))
>>> l((1,2,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#106>", line 1, in <module>
    l((1,2,3))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Why do I receive this error and how should I avoid it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Obviously if `f` returns a tuple of its arguments, and `l` is the result of calling `f`, `l` is going to be a tuple, which isn't callable. What do you _want_ it to be?

Comment: If you're trying to make `l` take variable arguments, then you don't want `*args` on `f`, you want `*args` on the lambda: `def f(x): return x`, then `l = f(lambda *args: len(args))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second example, `l` is not being assigned to what you think it is:

```
>>> def f (*args):
...     return args
...
>>> l = f(lambda x: len(x))
>>> l
(<function <lambda> at 0x020518A0>,)
>>>
```

As you can see, it is a tuple that *contains* the lambda function.  This is expected though because `*args` always collects its arguments into a tuple, which the function `f` then returns.

Later, when you do:

```
l((1,2,3))
```

a `TypeError` is raised for trying to call the tuple `l` as a function.

---

You can avoid this error by simply indexing the tuple to extract the lambda function:

```
l = f(lambda x: len(x))[0]
```

Now `l` refers to what it should:

```
>>> def f (*args):
...     return args
...
>>> l = f(lambda x: len(x))[0]
>>> l
<function <lambda> at 0x020169C0>
>>> l((1,2,3))
3
>>>
```

---

Although, as @abarnert said in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900213/lambda-expression-with-args/26900249#comment42353098_26900213), it looks like you are actually trying to make `l` take a variable number of arguments.  If so, then you need to use `*args` on the *lambda*, not function `f`:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x
...
>>> l = f(lambda *args: len(args))
>>> l(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
5
>>>
```

Remember that when you do `l(...)`, it is the lambda that is being called.  So, any arguments you give to `l` will be sent there.